# How to pass the value of "$@" as a single argument?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I wrote following Go code.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Println(os.Args)
}
```

Then compiled it...

```
$ go build -o out
```

And created following script `a.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -eu

./out "--opt1" "$@"
```

Then run `a.sh` and the result is:

```
$ a.sh hoge --foo bar
[./out --opt1 hoge --foo bar ]
```

I want to get `$@` as string. I expected `[./out --opt1 "hoge --foo bar" ]` as a result.

However they are splitted to array elements (by whitespace or `$IFS`?).
Is there any idea to get `$@`?

Comment: For most purposes, the behavior you seem to be seeking is exactly the wrong behavior.  If it's really what you want, `"$*"` is the ticket; but it's hard to imagine a situation where the possible benefits (which are however unclear to me) would outweigh the surprise to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `"$*"` instead.

Here's an example:

The function f1 uses `"$@"` to print its arguments, while `f2` uses `"$*"` to do the same.

```
f1() { printf '<%s>\n' "$@"; }
f2() { printf '<%s>\n' "$*"; }
```

Notice the differences in their output:

```
$ f1 a b c
$ <a>
$ <b>
$ <c>
$ f2 a b c
$ <a b c>
```

---

The difference between `$@` and `$*`:

- Without double quotes (**don't do this!**):
   There is no difference.
- With double quotes:
   `"$@"` expands to each positional parameter as its own argument: `"$1"` `"$2"` `"$3"`..., while `"$*"` expands to the single argument `"$1c$2c..."`, where 'c' is the first character of `IFS`.

Comment: There is a note about $* here http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html / The implementation of "$*" has always been a problem and realistically should have been replaced with the behavior of "$@". In almost every case where coders use "$*", they mean "$@". "$*" Can cause bugs and even security holes in your software.

Comment: @fzerorubigd You're partially correct. The problem is that you didn't read the question before posting this comment.

Comment: I read it, I think suggesting this is not a good idea, when there is other answer available to this.

Comment: @fzerorubigd OK. Post a better answer.

Comment: I think there is better answer for this available in bash world :) . my way is to change the go code too. simply using "--" as separator like all other bash utilities. for example there is no normal way (without -- ) to create a directory with name -rf in bash, unless using "mkdir -- -rf" why not pass the $@ after -- and then extract it in go code and join it?

Comment: @fzerorubigd Cool. OP might like to hear about your solution and maybe even consider using it. I do not want to open a broad discussion in the comments section.

Comment: Thanks. "$*" solved my issue, but I decided to use -- this time.

Answer (score 1):

### Go Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)   

func main() {
    for i, arg := range os.Args {
        fmt.Printf("Args[%d] = %s\n", i, arg)
    }
}
```

### Bash Code

```
#! /bin/bash

set -eu

./out "--opt1" "$*"
```

### Output

```
$ ./a.sh hoge --foo bar
Args[0] = ./out
Args[1] = --opt1
Args[2] = hoge --foo bar
```

### Explanation

[3.2.5. Special parameters](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_03_02_05) of the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) states:

> - `$*` — Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.
> - `$@` — Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.
>
> The implementation of "$*" has always been a problem and realistically should have been replaced with the behavior of "$@". In almost every case where coders use "$*", they mean "$@". "$*" Can cause bugs and even security holes in your software.

Comment: the [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) Bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. Instead, I suggest to use [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) by [Lhunath](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Lhunath) and [Greycat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat).